# O que fazer quando editar erroneamente uma pergunta?

Tags: suporte

Estava eu ajudando um novo membro e respondi a uma pergunta do mesmo, porém o membro precisava de mais algum detalhe na resposta.

Por uma vacilada acabei editando a pergunta e incluindo a resposta na edição da pergunta, tentei procurar uma forma de "reverter" a edição, mas não achei como.

O que fazer nesses casos? Esperar a edição ser rejeitada?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existe a opção **reverter**, mas **acredito** (especulação) que apareça apenas quando você possui mais que 2.000 de reputação, que é quando o sistema te considera confiável para edições.

O que aconteceu é que a sua edição entrou para a fila de análise. Ela provavelmente seria rejeitada - pelo menos é o que deveria acontecer. Sua edição foi aprovada pelo próprio autor da pergunta, possivelmente por desconhecimento da plataforma.

Até onde sei não existe uma forma de você remover a sua edição da fila de análise. Uma vez feita, precisa esperar que ela seja analisada.

Nesse caso, em que você percebeu que errou, basta esperar mesmo, mas pode acelerar o processo entrando no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) e contatando usuários que possuem reputação para avaliar a fila de edições solicitando que os mesmos rejeitem a edição.

Como a sua foi prontamente aprovada pelo autor, você pode fazer de forma semelhante, solicitando que algum usuário reverta a edição - a título de curiosidade, foi o que aconteceu. Eu percebi o erro e solicitei que um usuário revertesse a edição.

Acredito que a edição que originou a pergunta foi esta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/346008/revisions.

Comment: Exatamente @Anderson, foi esta pergunta mesmo

Answer (score 5):

Se a edição sequer foi aprovada, tem que esperar, porque ela fica bloqueando outra edição. Aí tem que ver se ela foi rejeitada ou aceita. A sua foi aceita.

Você tem duas possibilidades, a primeira óbvia é editar de novo consertando o que colocou de erro, e em muitos casos pode ser o melhor porque provavelmente nem toda edição estava errada. Para editar de novo é o mesmo processo de ter editado a primeira vez, clica em editar.

A segunda é reverter a edição como um todo, e faz sentido se tudo foi errado ou tem muito a reverter e **bem** pouco a aproveitar. Aí tem que clicar no marcador na postagem que indica que ela foi editada, porque quem e quando, ali entra em um *log* de tudo o que aconteceu com a pergunta, incluindo todas edições. Ali tem uma opção de **reverter** em cada edição, se clica nela irá voltar o conteúdo para aquele ponto do texto (obviamente a edição vigente não tem esse *link*).

Usando a pergunta em questão (note que ela já foi consertada por outro usuário):

[image: Log de edição]

Log:

[image: link reverter]

Comment: Maniero, poderia confirmar a informação de "reverter" aparecer apenas depois de certa reputação (ou aparece para todos)?

Comment: Até onde eu sei é para todos, afinal ela é uma edição como outra qualquer, é só um facilitador.

Comment: Mas a reversão entraria para a fila, caso o usuário tivesse menos de 2k? Estou tentando achar algo que fale sobre isso. Respondi dizendo que talvez não apareça a opção, mas foi por especulação por nunca ter visto uma reversão na fila e acredito que não faria sentido aprovar a reversão de quem não tem autonomia de editar.

Comment: Acredito que sim, porque é uma edição como outra qualquer, só foi originada de uma ação padrão de edição *full monty". Até usuário anônimo pode editar.

Comment: @Maniero Não lembro de ter visto esta opção "reverter", por isso abri o tópico, acredito que seja algo como o Anderson falou sobre os 2k de rep

Comment: @AlvaroAlves ainda vale a primeira opção, que quase sempre é a mais correta de ser usada, edite de novo corrigindo o erro inserido.